# PHP exec retorna "incorrect rpcuser or rpcpassword"

Tags: php

Estoy intentando integrar una nueva cripto moneda a un exchange, usando "chaucha-cli", pero al ejecutar el comando que crea la address, desde PHP con el comando exec, me arroja lo siguiente:

> incorrect rpcuser or rpcpassword

El código actual:

```
$command = "echo -e '' | sudo -S /home/user/chaucha-daemon/./chaucha-cli getnewaddress 2>&1 -rpcuser=user -rpcpassword=password";
```

Ejecutando dicho comando desde terminal, se ejecuta correctamente.

Comment: Ese es tu código en la app? osea lo tienes tal cual lo comentas aca?

Comment: Claro, luego con exec ejecuto ese comando y lo imprimo. Todo desde un archivo php

Comment: lo pregunto porque veo que en la scredenciales tienes en `-rpuser = user ` y en `-rpcpassword = password` y no creo que esas sean las credenciales

Comment: En realidad si son las mismas credenciales. El archivo chaucha.conf es el cual uno debe crear y asignarle las credenciales que contendrá :/